# Auto add custom taxonomy to permalink when save

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I've search this site and I can't find a way to automatically add custom taxonomy to a post permalink For example, I have a post with the title "mysamplepost" and taxonomy "years" with value "2018". So when I hit publish the post permalink becomes "https://example.com/mysamplepost-2018"

I saw this post [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254379/include-taxonomy-slug-in-post-url) but it doesn't function like I want to. Instead it inserts custom taxonomy before post title .

Thank you for whoever provides an answer

Comment: Do you want to append `2018` on the fly or want to append and store in database?

Comment: append on database also so make it permanent man

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code, you have to assign the custom taxonomy name to `$taxonomy` variable. And only the first taxonomy term will be appended to the post slug.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', function( $data, $postarr ) {
    /**
     * Only for post posttype and when the post is created
     */
    if ( empty( $postarr['save'] ) && isset( $data['post_type'] ) && 'post' === $data['post_type'] ) {
        $taxonomy  = 'custom-taxonomy-name'; // Add your custom taxonomy name
        $tax_terms = array();
        $slug      = '';

        /**
         * Make sure custom taxonomy is really assigned
         */
        if ( isset( $postarr['tax_input'] ) && isset( $postarr['tax_input'][ $taxonomy ] ) ) {
            $tax_terms = array_filter( $postarr['tax_input'][ $taxonomy ] );
        }

        /**
         * Only the first term slug will be appended
         */
        if ( count( $tax_terms ) ) {
            $term = get_term( current( $tax_terms ), $taxonomy );
            if ( ! is_wp_error( $term ) && ! is_null( $term ) ) {
                $slug = '-' . $term->slug;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Append the slug
         */
        if ( $slug ) {
            $data['post_name'] .= $slug;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: nice! its working great man ,. thanks a lot for your help. much appriciate!

Comment: Great! Good to hear that.